# data simulation from given covariance matrix from a regression model

Tags: chi-squared-test, simulation, linear, covariance-matrix, fitting

I have a set of data. I ran a linear model fit to the data, let's just say to a general form: $af_1(x)+bf_2(x)+cf_3(x)+df_4(x)+e$ where $a,b,c,d,e$ are the fitted parameters. I am able to get the covariance matrix of the parameters and the individual errors in the parameters as well. How would I be able to simulate "made-up"data that has the same covariance matrix about the best fit values of the parameters?

Comment: Could you explain what the "individual errors" are?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, standard error in the parameters, which are the sqrt of the diagonal entries in the covariance matrix. That was redundant in saying I have that and the covariance matrix since once gives the other. My question is asking how I can simulate a set of data that will fit to the same form with identical covariance matrix.